# Qt Signals and slots in a QThread

Tags: qt, post, upload, qthread

I am currently experiencing issues on a Qt thread.

I have to upload a list of files in a QThread, but apparently one upload doesn't work and/or my slots are never called. If I put the methods out of the thread it works perfectly.

Here is the run() method :

```
void UploadThread::run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Window::_listUpload.size(); i++) {
        qDebug() << Window::_listUpload[i].getPath();
        this->sendFile(Window::_listUpload[i].getPath());
    }
}
```

Here is the sendFile() method :

```
void UploadThread::sendFile(const QString & path)
{
    QFreeDesktopMime mime;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    QFileInfo fInfo(path);
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://my-url/"));
    QNetworkReply *reply;

    QString bound = "---------------------------723690991551375881941828858";
    QByteArray data(QString("--"+bound+"\r\n").toAscii());
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\n";
    data += "\r\n";
    data += QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toAscii();
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+fInfo.fileName()+"\"\r\n";
    data += "Content-Type: "+mime.fromFile(path)+"\r\n\r\n";

    QFile file(fInfo.absoluteFilePath());
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    data += file.readAll();
    data += "\r\n";
    data += QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toAscii();
    data += QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toAscii();
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"desc\"\r\n\r\n";
    data += "Description for my image here :)\r\n";
    data += "\r\n";
    request.setRawHeader(QString("Accept-Encoding").toAscii(), QString("gzip,deflate").toAscii());
    request.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Type").toAscii(),QString("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + bound).toAscii());
    request.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Length").toAscii(), QString::number(data.length()).toAscii());

    reply = manager->post(request, data);

    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)), currentThread(), SLOT(receiveUploadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), currentThread(), SLOT(uploadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}
```

And here are my slots :

```
void UploadThread::uploadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    _isFinished = true;
}

void UploadThread::receiveUploadProgress(qint64 bytesSent, qint64 bytesTotal)
{
    qDebug() << bytesSent << " " << bytesTotal;
}
```

Do you see a problem in my code ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I get it.

For each upload, I need to start the QEventLoop using exec(), and at the end of an upload I have to use exit() in order to finish the QEventLoop. It now works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be calling [`QObject::connect()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qobject.html#connect) in your `sendFile()` method.

`QObject::connect()` connects a signal with a slot method. The signal can be triggered using something like `emit signalName()`.

In your example, your UploadThread header should look like:

```
class UploadThread: public QThread {
    ...
signals:
    void uploadProgress(int sent, int total);
    void uploadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
}
```

Don't implement signals, they're automatically implemented by Qt.

In sendFile(), just call them:

```
...
emit uploadProgress(sent, total);
...
```

In your main thread (=gui thread) you then should have a class that has slots handling the signals (your current uploadFinished() and recieveUploadProgress() methods). If you want to update the GUI it's important that they're executed in the GUI thread.

Finally you have to connect them (connecting does not mean calling them) and start uploading.

```
UploadThread *uploadThread = new UploadThread();
connect(uploadThread, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(...)), objectInGuiThread, SLOT(actualUploadProgressSlot(...)));

uploadThread.start()
```

Have a look at Qt's [Signal & Slot](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt/signalsandslots.html) documentation on more information about how to use them.

Comment: I don't have to reimplement uploadProgress() and finished() signals, they are implemented by the QNetworkReply and QNetworkAccessManager respectively. I don't have to emit them manually. So, my code should work, no ?